# Matlab - "seal" a figure so that plotting won't overwrite it, but will create a new figure automatically

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, handle, figure

I'm writing a script that draws a figure. I'd like that figure to stay intact until it is closed by the user manually (e.g. clicking the cross).

If the user issues a plotting command in Matlab prompt, this should not affect the existing figure, but should open a new figure automatically.

How to block this default behaviour where Matlab reuses figure objects?

This may also be important when using a figure as an interactive user interface, that should not be replaced with some other content when the user wishes to plot something.

---

What I've tried: `help gcf` says that it retrieves the global `'CurrentFigure'` property. So, after plotting, I tried `set('CurrentFigure', 12345)`, hoping that it would reset the current figure to a nonexisting value (also tried zero, empty array). But that complains that it needs a handle. So I tried to instantiate a handle: `set('CurrentFigure', handle())`, but that complains that it's an abstract class. I guess I'm looking for a lightweight handle subclass that can be instantiated.

Comment: Could you show some sample code? If you put figure, plot(x,y) it will open a new figure every time.

Comment: @RDizzl3 Sample code is simple, like: `figure; plot([0 1], [1 2]);`. Then some other commands, that I'm asking for. After that, if the user types `plot(x, y)`, it should automatically open a new figure, not reuse the old one.

Comment: I agree it should not use the old one but it does. To fix that you just have to put figure before every plot so you will have a new figure/plot every time. Let me know if that works and I will add that solution to the answer board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the property `NextPlot` of the current figure to `new` will create a new plot on the next call to `plot()`. Here's a small example:

```
plot(1:10, 1:10); % create a figure
set(gcf, 'NextPlot', 'new'); % next plot goes in new figure
plot(1:10, 1:10);
```

The `CurrentFigure` property you tried to change just stores the handle to the figure that has been used/focused most recently. Its value must be a valid figure handle. You could of course just create a new empty figure with `figure()` which automatically sets `CurrentFigure` to the handle of the newly created figure. But then you have two figure windows open. Therefore I think the above method is a little more elegant.